# Trying to workout how to use quaternions to rotate a camera that is moving along a path to look in new direction vector

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to rotate the camera smoothly and without altering the y-vector of the camera direction, i can use look at, and it changes the camera direction in a flash, but this is not working for me, I would like a smooth transition as the direction of the camera changes.  I have been reading up, and not understanding everything, but it seems to me that quaternions are the solution to this problem.

I have this.object (my camera) moving along a set path (this.spline.points).  The location of the camera at any one time is (thisx,thisy, thisz)

I have cc[i]  the direction vector for the direction I would like the camera to face  (formerly I was using lookat(cc[i])  which changes the direction correctly, but too quickly/instantaneously)

Using info I have read, I have tried this below, and it just resulted in the screen going black at the point when the camera is due to move.

Could anyone please explain if I am on the right track, how to correct my code.

Thanks

```
var thisx = this.object.matrixWorld.getPosition().x.toPrecision(3);
var thisy = this.object.matrixWorld.getPosition().y.toPrecision(3);
var thisz = this.object.matrixWorld.getPosition().z.toPrecision(3);
var i = 0;
do {
    var pathx = this.spline.points[i].x.toPrecision(3);
    var pathz = this.spline.points[i].z.toPrecision(3);

    if (thisx == pathx && thisz == pathz){

    this.object.useQuaternion = true;
    this.object.quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(thisx, thisy, thisz, 1);
    var newvect;
    newvect.useQuaternion = true;
    newvect.quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion(thisx+cc[i].x, thisy+cc[i].y, thisz+cc[i].z, 1);

    var newQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

    THREE.Quaternion.slerp(this.object.quaternion, newvect.quaternion, newQuaternion, 0.5);
    this.object.quaternion = newQuaternion;


     //this.object.lookAt( cc[i]);
            i = cc.length;
    } else i++;

} while(i < cc.length);
```

Comment: Are you trying to rotate the camera around its own axis (i.e. change lookAt) or moving it around a fixed point (i.e. flyover effect)?

Comment: Trying to rotate on its own axis

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call this.object.useQuaternion = true. That is default behavior. 
Also, this.object.quaternion contains the current rotation, so no need to generate that either.

You might want to try a different approach - construct the rotation matrix from the spline position, lookAt and up vectors, creating a path of quaternions as a preprocessing step:

```
var eye = this.spline.points[i].clone().normalize(); 
var center = cc[i].normalize();
var up = this.object.up.normalize();
var rotMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().lookAt(eye, center, up);
```

You could then create the quaternions from the rotation matrix:

```
var quaternionAtSplineCoordinates = [];
quaternionAtSplineCoordinates.push(new THREE.Quaternion().setFromRotationMatrix(rotMatrix));
```

Once you have that path, you could apply the quaternion to the camera in your animation loop - provided you have a large enough number of samples. Otherwise, you could consider using slerp to generate the intermediate points.

Comment: Thanks, I shall give this a try when I get back home. :)

Comment: unfortunately this gives me a black screen.

Comment: Just to be clear,  cc[i] is the desired direction vector, it is not the vector to a target point, but rather a pure direction vector no matter where the camera is it will be looking in a parallel direction if we set lookat(cc[i])

Comment: The lookAt function creates a rotation matrix which will cause the camera to orient itself toward (face) the "center" given the "eye" (position) and an "up" vector (which is fixed). Is that what you are looking for? If possible, could you provide a fiddle to demonstrate the black screen?